# jquery fancybox display onload but with a delay

Tags: jquery

I can get my fancybox to display on page load, but it would great if it could be delayed just a second or two. Is there a way? This is what I have now:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#div_id").fancybox({

        //fancybox options

        });
        $("#div_id").trigger('click');
    });
```

I have tried a number of things to delay invoking the load and... no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div_id").fancybox({

    //fancybox options

    });
    // One second delay
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#div_id").click();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#div_id").fancybox({
          //fancybox options
      });
      $("#div_id").trigger('click');
   }, 1000);
});
```

See here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRNK2/)** - I have added a click alert and `fancy` class as an example.